# Relationship between vendor.js and application.js in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm just starting out in Webpack/ES6 and trying understand the relationship between a `vendor.js` and an `application.js` file. Based on what I've read online, a `vendor.js` is a good place to import external libraries (such as jQuery, Bootstrap etc), and an `application.js` file for application specific code.

Using the above approach, I've imported Bootstrap and [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) into my `vendor.js` file as follows:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
import 'bootstrap-select/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css';
import 'bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js';
```

It was then my understanding that I could then use bootstrap-select in my `application.js` file as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $('.my-select').selectpicker();
})
```

However, once I run Webpack and open a HTML file which loads the two bundles (as per below), I see this error in the console: `Uncaught TypeError: e(...).selectpicker is not a function`.

```
<script src="'core/static/dist/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="core/static/dist/application.bundle.js"></script>
...
<select class="my-select">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Barbecue</option>
</select>
```

Do I need to import something into `application.js`? The bootstrap-select code works fine in `vendor.js`, but I'm not sure how to utilise it in other bundles.

For reference, my `webpack.config.js` is:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    "mode": "development",
    "entry": {
        "vendor": "./core/static/js/vendor.js",
        "application": "./core/static/js/application.js"
    },
    "output": {
        "filename": "[name].bundle.js",
        "path": __dirname + "/core/static/dist"
    },
    "module": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "test": /\.css$/i,
                "use": ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    "plugins": [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Did you import `jquery` somehwere? I don't see its import

Comment: @RazRonen yeah - I've made ```jquery``` available globally using the webpack ```ProvidePlugin```.  jQuery works fine in the ```application.js``` file, I just can't use the ```.selectpicker();``` for some reason.